# NHibernate default schema is ignored for Sqlite

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

When using NHibernate schema export I configure it as follows:

```
Fluently().Configure
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
                .DefaultSchema("someschema")
                .Provider<SqliteInMemoryDriverConnectionProvider>()
                .ShowSql()
                .FormatSql()
                .Raw(Environment.GenerateStatistics, "true"))
```

However, when I look at the generated tables (using SchemaExport) they are generated like this:

```
Create table dbo_sometable ...
```

It looks like it's still using the standard dbo-prefix. How can I generate the table without the dbo-prefix?

More info:

I'm trying to run some integration tests using NHibernate in-memory. I do some NHibernate inserts and updates (they work fine, since they automatically add the schema prefix as well). I'm also doing some manual queries on the same tables though, that use just the table name. On live code this works fine (to a MS SQL Server database), in the test code it fails because it doesn't find the table `sometable`, since it was generated as `dbo_sometable`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your mapping set the schema.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I only have column mappings in there. In my live code it works fine, it's just in the test code that it doesn't work